# Seven fun mini-riddles

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, knowledge

Each of the following  represent a word or phrase. Can you figure them all out?

> Musical chairs, upgraded

> 4 and a castrated meteorology platform

> A long age, in the past

> Ding Dong 
>   A colours' rival with a fiendish compartment
>   A marketers money maker

> Come have a look! 
>   The evener?

> Me llamo viento

> First grade year for the Solomon Islands

Comment: are you sure these are rebuses? seem more like mini-riddles or cryptic clues

Comment: Yeah you're right, cryptic clues fits a lot better.There isn't really a tag that fits for that though. Guess I'll jut use riddle then.

Comment: Are the seven related to each other? Is there a common theme?

Answer (score 6):

*Partial answer...*

(I think) I have managed to crack the first.

Musical chairs, upgraded

> **Game of Thrones**
> I arrived at this by breaking it up into two phrases. {Musical chairs} is a game, and {chairs, upgraded} gave me thrones, which could be considered as upgraded versions of chairs.

Comment: You did indeed get the first

Comment: @Bard: So are the remaining six names of TV shows too? Or are they unrelated phrases?

Comment: They do follow a theme, but the theme isn't tv shows

Answer (score 6):

Guess I'll throw mine in here as well.

A long age, in the past

> ERA + GONE = Eragon

Answer (score 4):

Is Me llamo viento

> The Name of the Wind

And is the theme

> Book titles

Comment: Both of those are correct!

Answer (score 4):

I guess while we're all doing one...

Ding Dong
A colours' rival with a fiendish compartment
A marketers money maker

> The Belgariad (BELL + GARY (Pokemon reference - Red's rival) + AD)

Also it looks like these are specifically

> Fantasy novels.

Comment: This was my favourite one, and it just happens that all of the ones solved so far are fantasy.

Comment: @Bard ah, heh. That's interesting. I liked this one too - what is fiendish compartment referencing?

Comment: A monstrous pocket, or rephrased, a pocket that is monster

Comment: Hah, okay, that's pretty funny. :D